# How to set the length of an array using JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I need to create an array. The length must be set by using `JOptionPane`. Also I must then fill the array with random numbers. This is how far I got.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Aufgabe2
{
    public String a;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How big should the array be?");
        try
        {
            Integer.parseInt(a);
            int meinArray[];
            meinArray = new int[a];
            Random rand = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
            {
                meinArray[i] = rand.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(meinArray));
        }

        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println(a + " isn`t a valide input. Please insert a number");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok but what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the result of `Integer.parseInt(a)` to some variable and then use it e.g.

```
int x= Integer.parseInt(a);
int meinArray[];
meinArray = new int[x];
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    meinArray[i] = rand.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: This snippet wont compile.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing parsed integer assignment

```
        int size=Integer.parseInt(a);//you are missing int size= here

        int[] meinArray = new int[size];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            meinArray[i] = rand.nextInt();
        }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(meinArray));
```